# How to time a transformation in Spark, given lazy execution style?

Tags: apache-spark, benchmarking, pyspark

I have some code that is executing quite a few steps, and I know how long the whole process takes. However, I would like to be able to calculate how long each individual transformation takes. Here are some simple examples of the steps:

```
rdd1 = sc.textFile("my/filepath/*").map(lambda x: x.split(","))
rdd2 = sc.textFile("other/filepath/*").map(lambda x: x.split(","))
to_kv1 = rdd1.map(lambda x: (x[0], x[1])) # x[0] is key, x[1] is numeric
to_kv2 = rdd2.map(lambda x: (x[0], x[1])) # x[0] is key, x[1] is numeric
reduced1 = to_kv1.reduceByKey(lambda a, b: a+b)
reduced2 = to_kv1.reduceByKey(lambda a, b: a+b)
outer_joined = reduced1.fullOuterJoin(reduced2) # let's just assume there is key overlap
outer_joined.saveAsTextFile("my_output")
```

Now: how do I benchmark a specific part of this code? I know that running it end to end takes a certain amount of time (the `saveAsTextFile` will force it to execute), but how do I benchmark only the `reduceByKey` or `fullOuterJoin` part of the code? I know I could run `count()` after each operation to force execution, but that would not properly benchmark the operation since it is adding the time it takes to perform the `count` as well as the time to perform the transformation.

What is the best way to benchmark Spark transformations, given their lazy execution style?

Please note that I am NOT asking how to measure time. I know about the `time` module, `start = time.time()`, etc. I am asking how to benchmark given the lazy execution style of Spark transformations, which do not execute until you call an action that requires information to be returned to the driver.

Comment: you write "I know about the time module, start = time.time(), etc." what exactly do you mean by this? i'm searching for a way to time a single transformation / a set of transformations. thanks!

Comment: If you want to time a series of executions that ends with an action that forces execution, you can put `start = time.time()` at the beginning, `elapsed = time.time() - start` at the end after the action call, and then look at what `elapsed` contains.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your best bet is to use the Spark UI to read this information. The problem is two-fold:

- The computations are distributed so even if you added a timing mechanism inside each of the transformations, it would be somewhat difficult to tell when the task is truly done as it could be done in one machine, but not another. That said, you COULD add logging inside and find the first instance of the execution and then find the final execution. Keep in mind the next point though
- The transformations are pipelined as much as possible. So, Spark will run multiple transformations at the same time for efficiency, so you'd have to explicitly test JUST that one action.

Comment: I think the second point is very valuable here. I hadn't realized that Spark will run multiple transformations at the same time. My goal is more relative: which operations are taking the longest? Even if I can't time them exactly (my ideal situation), running `count` after each would give me a relative idea of which ones take a long time, then I can focus on making those actions more efficient (if possible).